# Need to pass the variable with same value from one function to another in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

i'm trying to pass the $customer_id variable from customer function to customerUpdate function , but i'm facing the error like 'undefined variable'

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
class CustomerDetailController extends Controller {
  public function customer (Request $request, $id){
      $customer_id = $id;
  }
  public function customerUpdate(Request $request) {
      dd($customer_id);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really study PHP OOP before starting to work with Laravel. In this case, you need `class properties` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: How will `customerUpdate` be called?

Comment: Please attach your route file contents. I am almost 100% sure that you are not using the routes as you should be.

Comment: Route::get('/customer-details/{id}', 'CustomerDetailController@getCustomerDetails')->name('customer-details');
 Route::get('/customer-details-update', 'CustomerDetailController@customerUpdate')->name('customerUpdate');

Comment: exactly as I thought. You are not sending the customer id in the update. Please go ahead and do some reading and look into Laravel controllers and routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a [class property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class CustomerDetailController extends Controller {
  
  private $customer_id;

  public function customer (Request $request, $id){
      $this->customer_id = $id;
  }

  public function customerUpdate(Request $request) {
      dd($this->customer_id);
  }

}
```

**UPDATE After your comment:**

As I said, you should really look into how PHP OOP works first. Then, go ahead and read about the Laravel controllers and routes and see how they work. Only then try to do something.

The way you are using the controller methods is not the way you are supposed to use them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests

Comment: i tried this , but i have get the NULL value in dd($this->customer_id);

Comment: if it's null, then you did not set the value before calling it. If you don't set a value in a NULL variable, and you try to dd the variable, you will ALWAYS get NULL :)